# RANKX function gives duplicates across all values it is ranking on

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Table with a measure calculating difference of a KPI across a unique combination of three categories. I am trying to rank the measure that is calculating the difference but I get repetitive ranks although the value being ranked is different.

Table:

[image]

What I tried:

```
Rank Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    RANKX(
        ALLSELECTED(Dim106),
        [Difference between spend in region and store],,
        DESC
    )
)

[Difference between spend in region and store] = StoreTurnover - RegionTurnover. 

RegionTurnover = CALCULATE(SUM(Dim106[Turnover |EJR|]),ALL(FactStore[Store ID]),ALL(FactStore[SOE]),ALL(FactStore[SOM]),ALLSELECTED(FactStore[Region]),ALLSELECTED(FactStore[YearMonth]),ALL(Dim106[WGI]),all(Dim106[Item Family]),ALL(Dim106[Item Subgroup]),ALL(Dim106[WGI Desc]),ALL(Dim106[Item Subgroup Desc]),ALL(Dim106[Item Family Desc]),ALL(Dim106[UniqueKey]))


StoreTurnover = CALCULATE(SUM(Dim106[Turnover |EJR|]),ALLSELECTED(FactStore[SOM]),ALLSELECTED(FactStore[SOE]),ALLSELECTED(FactStore[Store ID]),ALLSELECTED(FactStore[YearMonth]),ALLSELECTED(Dim106[Store]),ALLSELECTED(Dim106[Month]),ALL(Dim106[WGI]),ALL(Dim106[Item Subgroup]),ALL(Dim106[Item Family]),ALL(Dim106[WGI Desc]),ALL(Dim106[Item Subgroup Desc]),ALL(Dim106[Item Family Desc]),ALL(Dim106[UniqueKey]))

I have a fact table which has a higher hierarchy of store and and month, it has a crossfilter both directions relationship
```

Comment: Please provide the code for [Difference between spend in region and store], that seems to be the issue here. You used RANKX fine.

Comment: @JelleHoekstra when I create a unique key across the three categories, WGI, Item subcategory and item family and then rankx(all(dim106[uniquekey]),[difference between spend in region and store],,DESC) it works fine. I dont know how to specify all the three columns in the first parameter of the RANKX function

Comment: What's the DAX for: ```[Difference between spend in region and store]```? What seems likely, is that it behaves differently than expected when evaluated over a bigger context. This means that the value you are comparing each row to is different from what you expect, hence the strange ranking. It might vary when playing with the ```ALL()``` and ```ALLSELECTED()``` as the context changes.

Comment: @JelleHoekstra I have edited my question to include that. Its a big data model hard to explain

Comment: @JelleHoekstra it is giving me the count of rows rather than the rank

Comment: Thanks for the update, that explains the weird behavior. First, ```ALL()``` and ```ALLSELECTED()``` accept multiple arguments so repetition is not necessary and can probably be simplified as well. Second, what seems to be happening is that when your measure is computed over several rows per store it adds it up and then adds this total to each line when evaluating the ```RANKX()```, then the evaluation per single line will always be lower then the values stored in the previous evaluation hence the ```RANKX()``` yielding the same as a row count.

Comment: @JelleHoekstra sorry I am quite new to this, I sort of get what you are saying but could you guide me as to how I can correct my measures?

Comment: My recommendation would be to go back a step en rethink your calculations for region and store turnover and make sure they evaluate in different context as expected. Then you will have no issue running the ```RANKX()``` function. To help you with this I would need a clear understanding of your data model and columns, and a Power BI with dummy values would help. If you don't know what I mean by context, let me know, I'll share some links.

Comment: It probably works fine by chance, that's the point. I cannot find any good posts around but I recently tried in a response to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57782696/cant-measure-from-date-column/). Googling "explaining context power bi dax" yields plenty of useful results to get you started on your research.

Comment: @JelleHoekstra Please do share links. My turnover measures seem to be working fine. If I take a unique combination of the three columns I RANKX(all(dim106[uniquekey]),[diiference],,DESC) It works, when I add the WGI or any other column it again gives me row counts

Comment: In a nutshell, when you add a value field from a table to a visual in Power BI all the records in the table are used in the visual. You can add filters and slicers to specify which records are used in the total visual. As soon as you add categories these records get divided into groups and calculations will be evaluated over these smaller groups. Calculations for the total row when using a table will still use all records passed to the visual. Depending on your calculation, the expected result might not necessarily be what you expected as a consequence.

Comment: I know it can be a bit frustrating, but understanding context is the key to writing good DAX. The measures you provided contain a lot of in measure context specifications and exceptions, more than necessary, and enough to confuse me in understanding what is going on. That's why I strongly recommend researching and trying to understand the principle of context and starting over with your two initial measures. When you run into trouble and still have problems understanding, share your data model or sample Power BI, I might have some time this weekend to help you understand and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Richt click on your dataset fields `New Column` and use the following expression:

```
Rank Column = RANKX('YourTable';'YourTable'[YourColumn];;ASC)
```

**UPDATE:**

Maybe this suits your scenario:

```
RankingBySale = Rankx(All(Table1[SalesID], Calculate(Sum(Table1[SalesValue])), , Asc, Dense)
```

Comment: The value parameter is not a column, its a measure. So that wont work